# Load SPIR binary with clBuildProgram on Windows

Tags: opencl, spir

I am trying to load a SPIR binary i created with clang+llvm 6.0.1.

Created a few different files with :

```
clang -target spir-unknown-unknown -cl-std=CL1.2 -c -emit-llvm -Xclang -finclude-default-header OCLkernel.cl  
clang -target amdgcn-amd-amdhsa -cl-std=CL1.2 -c -emit-llvm -Xclang -finclude-default-header OCLkernel.cl  
clang -cc1 -emit-llvm-bc -triple spir-unknown-unknown -cl-std=CL1.2 -include "include\opencl-c.h" OCLkernel.cl
```

This is all happening on windows, installed AMD APP SDK 3 and Adrenalin 18.6.1 drivers.

After this i try to create a program from the binary :

```
clCreateProgramWithBinary(context, 1, &device, &programSrcSize, (const unsigned char**)&programSrc, 0 , &status)
```

This all goes OK, i don't get any errors here, but i do when trying to build it afterwards :

```
clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, " –x spir -spir-std=1.2", NULL, NULL);
```

The error i get is :

**Error CL_INVALID_COMPILER_OPTIONS when calling clBuildProgram**

I tried without the "-x spir..." stuff too, but then i just get a :

**error: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM6.0.1' Reader: 'LLVM 3.9.0svn')**

**EDIT:**

CL_DEVICE_NAME: gfx900
CL_DEVICE_VERSION: OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (2580.6)
CL_DEVICE_OPENCL_C_VERSION: OpenCL C 2.0
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 2580.6 (PAL,HSAIL)
CL_DEVICE_SPIR_VERSIONS: 1.2

After running **clCreateProgramWithBinary** i query the device with **clGetProgramBuildInfo** and get :
CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_TYPE = [CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_TYPE_INTERMEDIATE]

So that should mean the binary is being recognised, else i guess it would return CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_TYPE_NONE

**EDIT2:**

I think clang isn't creating a 'good' binary, but how to create it then?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you check the device info for `CL_DEVICE_SPIR_VERSIONS` to ensure SPIR is supported?

Comment: Yes, i edited my post. I have a Vega56. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the Khronos clang https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIR ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the support for SPIR was silently removed from AMD drivers, see dipak answers in this thread of AMD community forum:

https://community.amd.com/thread/232093

Regarding your second question: general clang+LLVM (not the secret version tuned by AMD and included in their proprietary drivers) still cannot produce binaries compatible with general-purpose Windows AMD drivers, however it is possible for Linux: [all new AMD’s ROCm, AMD PAL and Mesa 3D runtime are covered](https://llvm.org/docs/AMDGPUUsage.html).

It is a mystery for me why LLVM AMDGPU backend developers do not prioritize the task to produce binaries for Windows drivers, as there is a couple of GCN assembler projects that provide such a functionality through Windows OpenCL interface, to name a few: [CLRadeonExtender](http://clrx.nativeboinc.org/), [ASM4GCN](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/872477/Assembler-for-AMD-s-GCN-GPU), [HepPas](https://realhet.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/hello-world/), etc. Moreover I know an [undocumented fork of clang+LLVM](https://github.com/zawawawa/GCNminC) that (as its author states) produce such OpenCL binaries! "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy."